# Поиск математической проблемы для создания собственного асимметричного шифра (как RSA)

Tags: алгоритм, математика, криптография, шифрование

Скоро у меня будет написание диплома, я хочу создать свой шифр. Буду создавать гибридный шифр, смесь симметричного и асимметричного шифров. Симметричный я уже придумал, а вот асимметричный нужен для создания публичного и приватного ключей. Уже созданные алгоритмы типа RSA брать неинтересно.

Так вот, как правило, эти алгоритмы создания ключей используют математические проблемы (например, RSA - факторизация больших чисел, Диффи-Хелман - задача о дискретном логарифме). Какая есть интересная математическая проблема подобного характера?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Системы с открытым ключом, которые не используют дискретный логарифм в конечных группах, объединяют под флагом *пост-квантовой криптографии*. Это название подразумевает, что для дискретного логарифма в циклических группах можно адаптировать алгоритм Шора, какой бы группа ни была.

Подходы к [пост-квантовой криптографии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography):

- решётки (lattice-based),
- многочлены многих переменных (multivariate),
- коды восстановления ошибок (code-based),
- изогении суперсингулярных эллиптических кривых (Supersingular elliptic curve isogeny cryptography)

В 2016-22 гг NIST проводил [конкурс алгоритмов пост-квантовой криптографии](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/post-quantum-cryptography). В 2022-м были [выбраны победители](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/selected-algorithms-2022)

Берите, пишите свою реализацию.